# Tengo dos consultas las cuales necesito simplificar sus resultados

Tags: sql

la primera consulta, siempre trae datos

```
select centro_consumo.codcen, centro_consumo.nombre
from centro_consumo
```

la segunda consulta no siempre trae datos

```
select centro_consumo.codcen, centro_consumo.nombre
from centro_consumo 
inner join tb_quimi_elemento_gasto ele on centro_consumo.codcen=ele.codcen
where linea='ADM'`
```

Necesito mostrar lo siguiente, si la segunda consulta no me trae datos muestre todos los datos de la primera, y en el caso de existir datos en la segunda solo muestre los datos de la segunda.

Gracias por su apoyo al tema

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Tambien, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor como funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Podes ser mas claro, sobre como ejecutas las consultas y donde es que queres mostrar esto?

Comment: esto es ya mas logica de tu programacion que lenguaje estas usando..!!

Comment: para que funcione lo que quieres hacer tienes que usar un join diferente no el inner, primer punto investiga los tipos de join, segundo punto puedes usar isnull o coallease para poner isnull(dato1,dato2) que si el primero esta nulo muestre el sengundo, pero investiga esos temas y con eso lo arreglas

Answer (score 1):

Debes usar un left join en lugar de un inner join, esto hará que obtengas null cuando no encuentre la relacion con la tabla "tb_quimi_elemento" y así podrás diferenciar con un isNull o un Coalesce cuando mostrar un valor u otro (en tu pregunta no defines qué valores obtener de tb_quimi_elemento_gasto ni que motor de base de datos usas).

```
SELECT centro_consumo.codcen, centro_consumo.nombre
FROM centro_consumo 
LEFT JOIN tb_quimi_elemento_gasto ele ON centro_consumo.codcen=ele.codcen
WHERE linea='ADM'
```

Comment: Esta respuesta no esta mal, pero depende de en que tabla este linea ;)

Comment: en qué tabla esté línea? no lo entiendo, podrías explicarlo mejor?

Comment: haces linea=ADM. Si linea pertenece a la primer tabla, entonces este query no es igual al query original, ya que estaria filtrando resultados ;).

Comment: cierto, pero tiene pinta de que solo existe en la segunda tabla ya que solo lo consulta en su segundo query. :)

Comment: Estoy de acuerdo. peroooo.. nunca esta de mas que lo aclare ;)